# Creating a list of TextViews with borders that match the list width in Android

Tags: android, listview, row, listadapter

I'm trying to create a ListView of `TextView` elements, and I want that each row of the list to be enclosed in a rectangle shape.

The problem comes when the list shows up, and the rows (Rectangles) match their content instead of their parent `ListView`. I end up having something like this:

```
-------
.hello.
-------------
.How are you.
-------------
```

And I want something like this:

```
-------------
.hello      .
-------------
.How are you.
-------------
```

**Here is my row element xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@layout/popup_lonely_row">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/promo_row_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray_options" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is the row rectange shape xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/blue_alert_stroke" />

</shape>
```

Comment: try android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" on your shape.xml

Answer (score 0):

In your row rectangle shape use layout_width as match parent or fill parent